# send pdf base 64 ajax to java server

Tags: java, ajax, sockets

I am sending an ajax request that passes a pdf in base 64 code as a parameter to a java socket, but when I get the code in base 64 in some cases the server does not receive all the code.

the angular code:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:84',               
    data:$.param({acao: 'imprimi', file: dados.filebase64})

}).then(function (dados) {


});
```

the java code here:

[image: I could not put the java code so I am sending in an image]

and in the java I receive the  incomplete code.
I'm using java socket, when I get the base64 value I receive a string with null values.

[image]

Comment: So how is this related to `java`? Please remove the tag, it seems like we're dealing with `angular` instead.

Comment: What about the server code?